# What is a faster way to read binary as uint8, create sliding window of uint32, and find indices where the uint32 value == x?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some binary data to parse, and need to find where packets start. All packets start with the same header, but packet size is variable. The header is a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Below is my implementation, but it's slow. Is there some numpy functionality or other options to make this operation faster?

```
"""Example of binary data:

d9 37 b2 a5 08 31 03 ... 46 00 00 01 b9 1e 43 ... d9 37 b2 a5 30 90 06 00 cb... 08 00 30 43 d9 37 b2 a5 ... 04 01 c8 f4 ...

"""

def sliding_window(iterable, n=2):
    """Return a zipped object where each item is a sliding group of n elements from iterable.

    Example: 

    in = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    out = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7],[5,6,7,8]]

    """

    iterables = itertools.tee(iterable, n)

    for iterable, num_skipped in zip(iterables, itertools.count()):
        for _ in range(num_skipped):
            next(iterable, None)

    return zip(*iterables)


packet_header = 0xd937b2a5

dat_file = "path/to/file"
dat = np.fromfile(file=dat_file,dtype = np.uint8)
sw_u8s = sliding_window(dat,4)

#this is really slow
sw_u32s = [struct.unpack('>I', bytes(bb)) for bb in sw_u8s]

# then do something like 
# packet_start = np.argwhere(sw_u32s == packet_header)
# to find the indices of the packet headers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your array as `np.uint8`:

```py
import numpy as np
#                                      -v- packet header starts at byte 3
data_bytes = bytes([0x32, 0x12, 0x8a, 0xd9, 0x37, 0xb2, 0xa5, 0xf8, 0x3d])
dat = np.frombuffer(data_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Make a view of "windowed int32" values:

```py
dat_32win = np.ndarray((len(dat) - 3,), dtype=np.uint32, buffer=dat, strides=(1,))
```

Now you take your packet header in the byte order of your machine. In the likely chance that it is little endian, you need to reverse the order of the bytes (you can do this programmatically with `int.to_bytes` and `int.from_bytes` but it doesn't seem worth the trouble):

```py
packet_header_le = 0xa5b237d9
```

Now you just need to find the index of that value:

```py
idx = np.argmax(dat_32win == packet_header_le)
print(idx)
# 3
```

One note, if the packet header is not in the byte sequence, then that last `np.argmax` would return `0` (because its argument would be an array full of `False` values), which is the same result you would get if the packet header started at the first byte. You may want to handle that error condition checking that the packet header value is actually there.

Comment: This is great! Why did you elect to use argmax instead of argwhere?

Comment: @bass2 I assumed you wanted the index of the first occurrence of the packet header, which is what `argmax` will give you (unless the packet header is not in the data at all, as noted). `argwhere` would give you the index of all occurrences. I'm not sure what is more useful to you, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: @bass2 I changed the answer a little, in the previous answer some final bytes were discarded (e.g. if you had 11 bytes the last three would be discarded), so if the packet header happened to be partially there it would not be detected.